# Is there any method to skip some characters while reading csv

Tags: python, csv

i want to read a CSV file with python, it should have float precision of 9. but in some lines the file has non-numeric characters like

```
2925,0.826746422,>>0.641132847,0.732078005
2926,0.826746422,0.641132847*,0.732078005
2925,0.826746422,0.64113284700,0.732078005
```

How can i skip these characters, and tell python to take into consideration just 9 numbers after decimal point.

Comment: How are you reading the CSV? Is it through python's built-in CSV library or something else?

Comment: And what do you want to do with those lines? Discard them?

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff    I want to use CSV reader.

Comment: @Jan I want to consider them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with regex and with round in case there are too many digits:

```
import re
import csv

regex = re.compile(r"[^0-9.]")

with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        numbers = [regex.sub("",number) for number in row] #get rid of all characters
        numbers = [round(float(number.replace(",","."),9) for number in numbers] # round value to 9 digits
        print(numbers)
```

## Output

```
[2925.0, 0.826746422, 0.641132847, 0.732078005]
[2926.0, 0.826746422, 0.641132847, 0.732078005]
[2925.0, 0.826746422, 0.641132847, 0.732078005]
```

Comment: I used the code, it could read the file, but couldn't change to float, i think it is because in the file in some places two commas are used instead of one or even a point is used in a case. Even in some cases the last number is shifted to the next line, how can i solve this one.
379,0.510422071,,0.20966216,0.727347636
2895,0.123935667,0.18243965.0.265266884
1135,0.032502213,0.991668447
,0.717307047
1136,0.191534165,0.933957945,0.355540635

Comment: @MasoodRasoli see my edit that should do the tric. But the problem is maybe the csv reader will split it and therefore it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean the data on read.

```py
import csv
import re

data = []
with open('filename.csv') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    for row in reader:
        data.append([float(re.sub(r'[^0-9\.]', '', v)) for v in row])
```